# Download JSON file via JavaScript/JQuery - HTTP-Status Ok - JQuery Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, download

I've got the following problem: I need to download a `JSON` file from an `API` via **JQuery / JavaScript**. In theory this should be quite basic.

I tried `$.ajax` and all of its siblings like `$.get` or `$.getJSON`. I alway get an *200 OK* but my Firebug reports an error. Printing the error just says: "error" - so not that helful.

I read that maybe the JSON file is corrupt. So I tried it with a plain text file (*.txt). Same result.

The JSON file is valid, I check it against a validator.

I also tried `ContentType` and `dateType` and experimented with `json` and `jsonp`...

I basically used something like this (with a million variations for testing purposes):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://www.myurl.com/api/v1/myfile.json',
   ...
   success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
   error: function(error) {
     console.log(error.statusText);
   }
});
```

Am I missing something important here? It's really odd that nothing seems to change the behavior of the AJAX-call.

In fact I don't really need AJAX because I need to grab the JSON file when loading the page...

And the JSON file is not on the same domain as the AJAX caller.

Comment: no one will be able to help with just `error`, make a blank HTML page with just that request and see if it still occurs?

Comment: The JSON file itself may be malformed, can you provide a link to the actual JSON file you are trying to access?

Comment: try to use a **[JSON Parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)** to check if the response is really a valid JSON string

Comment: sorry, forgot to point out that i already checked the json file. i updated my post.

Comment: @epoch: Good idea! But still no luck. The `error.statusText` is *success* and `error.message` is *undefined*...

Comment: @Ron, i will be shunned for this, but try a different jquery, different machine and different json file.

Comment: you really think that the problem lies within jquery1.8? i checked firefox and chrome so far. exact same behavior...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that URL located on the **same server** you're trying to get the data from?

If not, you ran into a cross-domain request, which can only be handled using JSONP. So, the JSON file itself must be compatible with JSONP format, otherwise jQuery won't be able to process it (even if you provide a 'jsonp' dataType).

P.S.: Firebug will always show response code 200 but give an empty response body for such requests

Comment: how can i check if a json file is jsonp compartible?

Comment: check [JSONP docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and [this URL from Google Feed API](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&&callback=processResults&q=http://stackoverflow.com/feeds) - that should provide you with a solid start

Comment: P.S.: if the web on the other side would allow you to request data from your server, it would also work for you - for that, they'd need to be sending [cross-domain headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) for you to allow it

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way by disabling security

```
$.ajax( {
        type : 'GET',
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url : surl,  \\specify  your url
        async : false,
        dataType : 'json',
        headers : {
            Accept : "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
        },
        crossDomain : true,
        success : SucceedFunc,
        error : function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error" + ' ' + JSON.stringify(data) + ' ' + textStatus + '  ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
function SucceedFunc(data) {
               alert("success");
                   }

    }
```

Comment: I changed `dataType` to *jsonp*, then I get the following: error {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"} parsererror  Error: jQuery18008677731226247496_1346769531305 was not called

Comment: add &callback=? at the end of the url as http://www.myurl.com/api/v1/myfile.json&callback=?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to catch the error the correct way?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.myurl.com/api/v1/myfile.json',
    success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
         console.log(error.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, i used `console.log("error: "+error.statusText)`. `error.message` returns *undefined*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome go to cmd prompt and run the chrome by disabling the security. You can disable security using pathwhere_chrome_is_located\chrome.exe  --disable-web-security
and run the html page. I think this may help you.